# LONG: How does .finally in Promise work differently in terms of event loop and tasks scheduling?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, scheduled-tasks, chaining

I'm trying to dive deep into promises and event loop to strengthen my understanding of them and this (completely useless, not practical) is the code I've just written:

```
let a = Promise.resolve('Hello everyone!')
    
a.then(function first(x) {console.log(x); return x})
    
.then(function second(x) {console.log(x); return x})
.then(function third(x) {console.log(x); return x})
.then(function fourth(x) {console.log(x); return x})
.then(function fifth(x) {console.log(x); return x})
.then(function sixth(x) {console.log(x); return x})
.then(function seventh(x) {console.log(x); return x})
.then(function eighth(x) {console.log(x); return x})
      
    
 let b = Promise.resolve(true);

b.catch(function bFirstThen(x) {console.log(x)})
.finally(function bFinally() {console.log('Its done')})
.then(function bThen(x){ console.log('The value is:', x)})
```

This prints the following in the console:

```
    Hello everyone!
    Hello everyone!
    Its done
    Hello everyone!
    Hello everyone!
    Hello everyone!
    The value is: true
    Hello everyone!
    Hello everyone!
    Hello everyone!
```

However, when I wrote the code, I expect it to print:

```
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
Its done
hello everyone;
The value is: true
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
```

Because thats how I expected the code to work:

1. Our code (in the first tick) will run synchronously, going through each line and if there's any task to run later, we'll put them onto the microtask queue for later execution after all our sync code is done!
2. In the first line, we create and immediately resolve a promise so know we know any function we have inside our a.then (in our case its only one) will immediately be put onto the microtask queue for later execution!
3. We hit this line of code **"x => {console.log(x); return x}"** and since our promise is already resolved, this task will be put inside our microtask queue for later execution and also return a pending promise! So right now, our microtask queue looks something like this **microtaskQueue = [function first(x) {console.log(x); return x}]**
4. Then we have 7 .then thats under the hood is setting up those functions inside hidden Promise's array called onFulfilmet. Since the promises are not resolved, their handlers wont be put onto the microtask quite yet so our microtask queue still has only one task to run after our sync code.
5. The next two meaningful lines we have in our example are **"let b = Promise.resolve(true);"** and  **"b.catch(x => {console.log(x)})"**
6. Note that our Promise is resolved however, we're doing .catch instead of .then! Quite sure this is something that you always wanna be avoiding but right now, for example's sake, lets concur with that!
7. After all our sync code, this is what our microtask queue looks like: **microtaskQueue = [function first(x) {console.log(x); return x}, function bFirstThen(x) {console.log(x)}]**
   **8. All our sync code is done which means now it'll start taking tasks from the microtask queue and start running tasks one by one and if we hit any code that registers another microtask queue, we will!**
8. This is our first function from the microtask queue to run "function first(x) {console.log(x); return x}" This is pushed into the callstack and when run, it prints "Hello everyone!" and return x which means "Hello everyone!" Once this code is finished, this registers another task so now our microtask queue looks like this: **microtaskQueue = [function bFirstThen(x) {console.log(x)}, function second(x) {console.log(x); return x}]**
9. We take the first task again from our microtask queue (which happens to be this function: **function bFirstThen(x) {console.log(x)}**) and and put onto the callstack to run! Since we got this handler from a .catch method and our promise was resolved (not rejected) this function doesn't run and that .catch promise is now evaluated to a resolved promise!
10. AS soon as it does so, we push the next function into the microtask queue so now our microtask queue looks like this: **microtaskQueue = [function second(x) {console.log(x); return x}, function bFinally() {console.log('Its done')}]**
11. Pretty straight forward for this function again (function second(x) {console.log(x); return x}) as this will print "Hello everyone!" for the second time and register another handled into the microtask queue so now our microtask looks like this: **microtaskQueue = [function bFinally() {console.log('Its done')}, function third(x) {console.log(x); return x}]**
12. We now take this function from our microtask queue (function bFinally() {console.log('Its done')}, ) puts it into the callstack and run the code inside it which is just a simple log of "Its done"! As we know .finally neither cant take the value from the previously returned promise, neither can it return a value to be used by the next promise. So what this will do is run the code inside it and our earlier written .finally(..) code will evaluate to a resolved promise again as our root promise is resolved!
13. Since we have a resolved promise this way, it will register it's task to the microtask queue so now our microtask queue looks like this: **microtaskQueue = [function third(x) {console.log(x); return x}, function bThen(x){ console.log('The value is:', x)}]**
14. we take the first task as usual from our list, run it, which in our case will again log "Hello everyone", and register this function "function fourth(x) {console.log(x); return x}" this is our microtask now: **microtaskQueue = [function bThen(x){ console.log('The value is:', x)}, function fourth(x) {console.log(x); return x}]**
15. When we run this function (function bThen(x){ console.log('The value is:', x)},) it will print "The value is: true"
16. After that, Hello everyone should be printed three times more and hence this should be our final logs:

```
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
Its done
hello everyone;
The value is: true
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
hello everyone;
```

However it doesnt!

What am I missing in this whole equation?

Comment: It's OK to be curious about these inner workings, but just realize that any REAL code that needed a certain execution order would write the code to force a specific execution order and would not rely on any understanding of the level of detail you're asking about here.  And, some of this level of detail has changed in the spec over time too - further why your code should not rely on it.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yeah I'm a javascript intermediate-beginner who havent worked practically yet so I wanna clear these doubts first before moving on to the next productive things. :) Are you sure this is something I'll never encounter in my life? (Sorry as I said, I dont have work experience at all)

Comment: If precise timing is required between independent promise chains, then you have to write the code to control that timing.  Since real asynchronous operations have unpredictable timing behind them (unlike you're make-up chains here that don't represent real asynchronous operations), the nuances of the timing question here are largely irrelevant in any real world coding.  I have literally NEVER needed to know this in all my JS promise programming.  If somewhere down a promise chain A has to happen before B, you must write code to ensure that because real world timing is not predictable anyway.

Comment: If you look at my answer history here on stackoverflow, I've answered a lot of these questions before and have recently decided it's largely pointless, other than for pure academic curiosity.  Make each of your promises and `.then()` handlers resolve with a random or unpredictable delay (like real world asynchronous operations) and you will see how this type of issue becomes irrelevant to determining when the fourth step in two competing promise chains gets executed.  It will have ONLY to do with the resolved timing of the previous steps in the chain.

Comment: If you're curious, you can still pursue an answer (I'm not discounting academic curiosity), just trying to put some perspective on what actually happens in real world code.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I see, thanks a lot for sharing the knowledge! :)